# How to plot multiple curves for different values of a certain parameter in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that contains several parameters and I want to examine each parameter effect on the function by using multiple values, the problem is that I find it so difficult to change the value of a parameter and change it each time and plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

B = 0
B1 = 0.01
phi = 1
Da = 10
M = 0
Re = 100
dP = 1
a = phi * ( (1/Da) + M**2 )
c = 1 * phi * Re * dP

k = ( c * np.exp( 0.5 * np.sqrt(a)) ) / ( (a) * ( np.sqrt(a) * B * ( np.exp(0.5 * np.sqrt(a)) )**2 - np.sqrt(a) * B + ( np.exp(0.5 * np.sqrt(a)) )**2 + 1) )

x = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,100)
f = lambda x: (c/a) - k * ( np.exp( x * np.sqrt(a) )+ np.exp( -1 * x * np.sqrt(a) ))
fp = f(x)

plt.plot(fp,x)
plt.xlabel('fp')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.xlim(0, 13)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
plt.legend(['Initial case','Initial case,B=0.01'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/N3J009y
https://ibb.co/1RvtnDc
https://ibb.co/NZ5WWv2
https://ibb.co/tPPXS3z

Comment: Write a function that takes the parameter(s) you wish to be different as arguments. Then call the function for each of your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a function which will accept whatever parameters you want.  Here we can place default parameters in the function declaration, and then below create a list of values for `Da`.  Loop over that list and plot, then after the loop finishes set your plot specifics and display the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [12, 8]


# Function defined with default values if none are passed
def math_func(B=0,B1=.01,phi=1,Da=10,M=0,Re=100,Dp=1):
    a = phi * ( (1/Da) + M**2 )
    c = 1 * phi * Re * dP
    k = ( c * np.exp( 0.5 * np.sqrt(a)) ) / ( (a) * ( np.sqrt(a) * B * ( np.exp(0.5 * np.sqrt(a)) )**2 - np.sqrt(a) * B + ( np.exp(0.5 * np.sqrt(a)) )**2 + 1) )
    x = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,100)
    f = lambda x: (c/a) - k * ( np.exp( x * np.sqrt(a) )+ np.exp( -1 * x * np.sqrt(a) ))
    return f(x),x

# All of the values you want to check for this parameter
Da_range = [.01,.1,1,10]

for Da_n in Da_range:    
    # Plot all of your lines
    fp,x = math_func(Da=Da_n)
    plt.plot(fp,x, label=f'Da={Da_n}')

# Set Plot Details
plt.xlabel('fp')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.xlim(0, 13)
plt.ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]